# PHP Converting CSV to XLS - phpExcel error

Tags: php, excel, csv

I have written an Export script that will export data from my database as a CSV or XLS file. The data from the database needs to be manipulated first. So far I have the CSV file working and am now trying to convert this CSV string to XLS.  I want to use [**phpExcel**](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/tree/develop/Classes/PHPExcel) but get the below error.  Can anyone assist?

```
Fatal error:  Class 'PHPExcel_Exception' not found in /var/www/leanne/api/library/PHPExcel/Exception.php on line 36
```

Code which is causing the error, all worked fine until I added the XLS stuff:

```
if($format == 'csv'){  
                //create and write to file for CSV
                if(file_exists($file_location . $filename)){
                    unlink($file_location . $filename);
                }
                $fh = fopen($file_location . $filename , 'a');
                fwrite($fh, $csv);
                fclose($fh);
            } else if($format == 'xls'){ 
                //wite to file for XLS
                include '../library/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

                $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('CSV');
                $objReader->setDelimiter($separator); 
                $objReader->setEnclosure(" ");
                $objReader->setLineEnding($endrow);

                $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($csv);
                $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
                $objWriter->save($file_location . $filename);               

            }
```

NB: csv is a string containing comma separated and double quoted fields from the database.  The lines end with '\n'.

Comment: what kind of database is it? mysql?

Comment: if it's mysql you can export it directly using code here http://www.jamesnorthard.com/export-mysql-to-excel-using-php/

Comment: SQL SERVER. The error is to do with the PHPExcel plugin as it all worked fine before adding this.

Comment: what version of sql server? sorry for being picky

Comment: I already have the CSV string which has been manipulated quite a lot and therefore exporting the data straight from the database is not what I want. thanks.

Comment: oh i was going to suggest http://sourcecodemaster.com/php/how-to-export-mysql-data-to-csvexcel-file-using-php/ but if you've manipulated it already then i guess that's redundant

Comment: try including the phpexcel_exception class directly. Most likely you have some trouble with relative paths.

Comment: I don't think your error is the exception. I think the class is error-ing and trying to call the exception when it does. Your error might be totally unrelated to this output.

Comment: Do you have an autoloader that might clash with PHPExcel's autoloader?

Comment: @hob - You'd seriously suggest that HTML markup + .xls headers creates an .xls file?

Comment: Hi Mark, you may be onto something, I do have an autoloader.  Any ideas on how I get round this?

Comment: Depends on the details of your autoloader: if you're simply using __autoload(), then switch to using spl_autoload_register(); or if (for example) it throws an Exception if it can't find a file (like the Yii autoloader) then you need to ensure that the PHPExcel autoloader fires first.

Comment: ok, mu autoloader uses spl_autoload_register(); I have therefore  included PHPExcel before my own autoloader and initiated $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('CSV'); before anything else.  I still get the same error

Comment: Well start by checking that the Exception.php file is under library/PHPExcel (the same directory as Autoloader.php and IOFactory.php); check that your autoloader isn't trying to handle PHPExcel classes rather than passing them through to the PHPExcel autoloader, etc

Comment: I have removed my own autoloader and still I get the same error.  I have checked and Exception.php is where it should be.  I have run the test file simple01.php and that runs fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ive downloaded the files again and started from scratch and its working.  Must have been something silly I had done, sorry for wasting your time and thanks for the help.