# Convert csv to excel with PHPExcel in laravel?

Tags: php, excel, csv, laravel, laravel-excel

i have found this answer ,

[PHP Converting CSV to XLS - phpExcel error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566328/php-converting-csv-to-xls-phpexcel-error)

but i have tried it in Laravel 4 and i am not able to get it to work , any help would be appreciated.

My Code

```
    public function CsvExcelConverter($filename){
        $objReader = Excel::createReader('CSV');
        $objReader->setDelimiter(";");
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load('uploads/'.$filename);
        $objWriter = Excel::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
       //new file
       $new_filename = explode('.',$filename);
       $new_name = $new_filename[1];
       $objWriter->save($new_name.'.xls');
       return $new_name.'.xls';
    }
```

Comment: Where is your code? Do you want to use http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs ? You should provide your code and sample CSV file

Comment: Hello Thanks for the reply; yes i am using maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs , and i found the code in the example but system complains that function createReader and createWriter do not exist.

Comment: You should put your code into question

Answer (score 1):

thank for the answers, but for some reason we cant seem to set the delimiter on load but i have found that you can set it in the config file .

vendeor/maatwebsite/excel/src/config/csv.php

then just specify the delimiter. this way when loading the file it actually separates each entry and when converting it each entry is in its own cell.

thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Get the excel.php class here: http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/1919.html */
require_once("../classes/excel.php");
$inputFile=$argv[1];
$xlsFile=$argv[2];

if( empty($inputFile) || empty($xlsFile) ) {
    die("Usage: ". basename($argv[0]) . " in.csv out.xls\n" );
}

$fh = fopen( $inputFile, "r" );
if( !is_resource($fh) ) {
    die("Error opening $inputFile\n" );
}

/* Assuming that first line is column headings */
if( ($columns = fgetcsv($fh, 1024, "\t")) == false ) {
    print( "Error, couldn't get header row\n" );
    exit(-2);
}
$numColumns = count($columns);

/* Now read each of the rows, and construct a
    big Array that holds the data to be Excel-ified: */
$xlsArray = array();
$xlsArray[] = $columns;
while( ($rows = fgetcsv($fh, 1024, "\t")) != FALSE ) {
    $rowArray = array();
    for( $i=0; $i&lt;$numColumns;$i++ ) {
        $key = $columns[$i];
        $val = $rows[$i];
        $rowArray["$key"] = $val;
    }
    $xlsArray[] = $rowArray;
    unset($rowArray);
}
fclose($fh);

/* Now let the excel class work its magic. excel.php
    has registered a stream wrapper for "xlsfile:/"
    and that's what triggers its 'magic': */
$xlsFile = "xlsfile://".$xlsFile;
$fOut = fopen( $xlsFile, "wb" );
if( !is_resource($fOut) ) {
    die( "Error opening $xlsFile\n" );
}
fwrite($fOut, serialize($xlsArray));
fclose($fOut);

exit(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `maatwebsite/excel` library in Laravel, you can only use native PHPExcel instance methods, not static methods. To convert from CSV to excel, this code can be found at [Documentation page](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/export#store)

```php
Excel::load($filename, function($file) {
    // modify file content
})->setFileName($new_name)->store('xls');
```

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you should create your custom class to set delimiter:

```
class CSVExcel  extends Excel {
    protected $delimiter  = ';';
}
```

and now you could use:

```
CSVExcel::load('csvfilename.csv')->setFileName('newfilename')->export('xls');
```

But the problem is, that `$delimiter` isn't used in this case. Delimiter support seems to be added not long time ago, so maybe there is a bug or it needs to be used in the other way. I've added issue just in case for that: https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/262